# Using wildcards in keyup function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get keyup to work with wildcards so it can match similar URL's as opposed to exact URLs but * ain't working, what am I doing wrong ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fname").keyup(function () {
        if(this.value == "*.drive.google.com/*"){
            $('#input').css("display", "block");
        }else{
            $('#input').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just pass in a `*` to an equality comparison, I would do something like this:

```js
let generateValidator = (str) => {
  const pieces = str.split('*');
  let regex = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
      if (pieces[i] === '') {
         regex += '.+';
      } else {
          regex += pieces[i].replace(/\./, '\\.'); 
      }
  }
  let rule = new RegExp(regex);
  return (url) => {
      if (!url.startsWith('http')) {
         url = `http://${url}`;
      }
      try {
          new URL(url);
      } catch (e) {
          return false;  
      }
      return rule.test(url);
  }
}

let isValid = generateValidator('*.drive.google.com/*');

let valid = {
    "www.drive.google.com/test": isValid("www.drive.google.com/test"),
    "drive.google.com": isValid("drive.google.com"),
    "abc.drive.google.com/world": isValid("abc.drive.google.com/world"),
    "#421.drive.google.com/test": isValid("#421.drive.google.com/test")
}

console.log(valid);
```

And then in your code, you could just do:

```
<script>
let isValid = generateValidator('*.drive.google.com/*');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fname").keyup(function () {
        if(isValid(this.value)){
            $('#input').css("display", "block");
        }else{
            $('#input').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```